# Using ZX calculus to postselect the first round of a distance-2 rotated surface code

Tags: error-correction, zx-calculus

I'm translating gate model language to ZX calculus diagram using such notation, to describe the first round of measurement of such a distance-2 rotated surface code below.
[image]

I wrote this diagram where time flows from top to bottom, using nodes to describe initial states (all qubits initialized in |+>) and post-selection (ancillas all measured 0 in X basis). Then I simplified the diagram using those rewriting rules and got the diagram on the right. Which, when I translated into gates in a statevector simulator and do a second round of stabilizer measurement, doesn't give all zeros.
[image]

My diagram is probably wrong in the first place, how should I use ZX calculus for this toy problem?

Comment: I think you made a mistake when simplifying the diagram. The initial diagram looks correct to me. You can use https://zx.cduck.me/ to do rewrites that are guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: Thank you Craig